# Concatenation not working inside of function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am converting minutes to days and hours. When I am using following code, it works fine

```
declare @theMinutes int
Set @theMinutes = 1449 

select cast(@theMinutes / 1440  as varchar)
        + ' Day(s) '+ cast((@theMinutes % 1440 / 60) as varchar)      
        + ' Hour(s) '+ cast(@theMinutes % 60    as varchar)    
        + ' Minute(s)' AS COLUMN_A
```

and displays result

```
1 Day(s) 0 Hour(s) 9 Minute(s)
```

But when I use this to write a function, then it is only returning 1, the rest things are not getting concatenated

```
Create function [dbo].[ConvertMinToDays]
(
    @theMinutes int
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN   
    Declare @convertedStr varchar(200)

    SET @convertedStr =  cast(@theMinutes / 1440  as varchar(10)) + ' Day(s) ' 
    + cast((@theMinutes % 1440 / 60) as varchar(10))+ ' Hour(s) ' 
    + cast(@theMinutes % 60 as varchar(10)) + ' Minute(s)';  

    return  @convertedStr;

END

GO

SELECT dbo.ConvertMinToDays(1449) as COLUMN_A
```

Can Anybody help me , where i am going wrong ??

Comment: Defining a parameter (or return value) as just `varchar` (*without* defining a length) defaults to **1 character** length.....

Comment: Thanks , i forgot the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
RETURNS varchar
```

to

```
RETURNS varchar(200)
```

I'm assuming its only going to return one character otherwise

Comment: Glad to help @MandeepSingh

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a varchar

Change it to

```
RETURNS varchar(200)
```